# How do I identify out the global Rails settings in a custom COP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

My cop:

```
# lib/rubocop/cop/myproject/my_cop.rb

require 'rubocop'

module RuboCop
  module Cop
    module MyProject
      class MyCop < RuboCop::Cop::Cop
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This cop needs to know some global settings Rails. For example, `Rails.logger.log_level`

But I get errors:
1) `undefined method 'logger' for RuboCop::Cop::Rails:Module` - when I call `Rails.logger.log_level`
2) `uninitialized constant Rails` - when I call `::Rails.logger.log_level`

**Can this be done or is it a stupid idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option you can do:

```
# lib/rubocop/cop/myproject/my_cop.rb

require 'rubocop'
require_relative '../../../../../config/environment'

module RuboCop
  module Cop
    module MyProject
      class MyCop < RuboCop::Cop::Cop
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And call `::Rails.logger.level`

Answer (score 1):

Rubocop is a *static* code analyzer. Which means when you run `rubocop` command, it does not load any ruby environments, including Rails. It just reads ruby files and analyses those as text files.

So the short answer is: no, it can not be achieved with Rubocop.